# Need to find specific number from multiple number in an alphanumeric string

Tags: vba, excel-formula, split, text-extraction

From below string I need to find 63612067 though formula or VBA.

KD 63612056 Added, KD 63612067 Added, KD 63612075 Added, ENG NA

I have the unique numbers in column A in sheet1 and the strings as mentioned above in sheet2 in column A. I want to find value available in cells of column A of sheet1 from the cells of column A of shhet2.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you clarify the setup and the logic you need to follow? Are the strings listed one per row on sheet 2? Are the numbers always the same length?

Comment: a sample set of data and the lookup logic is vital to solve a question like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the part of the question beginning with "I have the unique..." but ignoring that part this code might help:

```
Dim s as String, arrS() as String, t as String, arrT() as String, result as String
   s="KD 63612056 Added, KD 63612067 Added, KD 63612075 Added, ENG NA"
   arrS=Split(s,",")
   t=arrS(2)
   arrT=Split(t," ")
   result=arrT(1)
```